# how to center my divs after media query and green size changing?

Tags: html, css

well,i'm making my first website, and I want to make Menu page like here https://62bc5048ee1d4.site123.me,when my screen size is lower than 762px,i don't know why but first and third photo is floated to left side, but second and fourth is good centred,please check the link to know what I mean and how my page should look like,here is my html:

```
 <section id="part2">
     <div class="container" id="special">
         <h1 class="topper-header">BLOG</h1>
         <div class="box1">
             <img class='blog-image' src="images/img1-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
             <h3>10 RULES TO BUILD A WILDLY</h3>
             <p>You can edit all of this text and</br> replace it with anything you have</p>
             <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
             <img class='blog-image' src="images/img3-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
             <h3>9 STEPS TO STARTING A BUSINESS</h3>
             <p>This is a generic blog article you</br> can use for adding blog content</p>
             <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
             <img class='blog-image' src="images/img2-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
             <h3>7 BIG THINGS A START-UP MUST HAVE TO</h3>
             <p>You can also change the title</br> listed above and add new blog</p>
             <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
         </div>
         <div class="box1">
             <img class='blog-image' src="images/img4-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
             <h3>HOW TO MAKE EXTRA MONEY</h3>
             <p>Edit your Blog articles from the</br> Pages tab by clicking th </p>
             <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

and my CSS:

```
#part2{
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:100px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.box1{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

.box1 li{
    color:#00ced1;
    font-size:15px;
}


.box1 h3{
    margin-top:0px;
    color:#00ced1;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}

.box1 p{
    padding-bottom:0px;
    font-size:15px;
}


.blog-image{
    padding-right:18px;
    padding-left:5px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:0;
}

@media all and (max-width:1200px) {
    .topper-header{font-size:240%;}


    .blog-image{width:230px; height:150px;}
    .box1 h3{font-size:16px;}
    .box1 p{padding-bottom:0;font-size:15px;}

}

@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
    .box1{width:40%;float: none;}
    .blog-image{width:100%; height:250px;padding-bottom:5px;}
    .box1 li{margin-top:-8px;font-size:15px;}
    .box1:nth-child(odd) {margin-left: 1rem /*or other value*/;}
    #special {display: flex;flex-direction: row;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center;}


@media all and (max-width:762px) {

    #special {display:table;align-content: center;float:none;width:50%;}
    .blog-image{width:370px; height:270px;}
    .box1 p{float:left;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#part2{
    margin-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:100px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.box1{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

.box1 li{
    color:#00ced1;
    font-size:15px;
}


.box1 h3{
    margin-top:0px;
    color:#00ced1;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}

.box1 p{
    padding-bottom:0px;
    font-size:15px;
}


.blog-image{
    padding-right:18px;
    padding-left:5px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:0;
}

@media all and (max-width:1200px) {
    .topper-header{font-size:240%;}


    .blog-image{width:230px; height:150px;}
    .box1 h3{font-size:16px;}
    .box1 p{padding-bottom:0;font-size:15px;}

}

@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
    .box1{width:40%;float: none;}
    .blog-image{width:100%; height:250px;padding-bottom:5px;}
    .box1 li{margin-top:-8px;font-size:15px;}
    .box1:nth-child(odd) {margin-left: 0rem /*or other value*/;}
    #special {display: flex;flex-direction: row;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center;}
    h1.topper-header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}}


@media all and (max-width:762px) {
    #special {display:table;align-content: center;float:none;width:50%;}
    .blog-image{width:370px; height:270px;}
    .box1 p{float:left;}
}
```

```html
<section id="part2">
 <div class="container" id="special">
     <h1 class="topper-header">BLOG</h1>
     <div class="box1">
         <img class='blog-image' src="images/img1-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
         <h3>10 RULES TO BUILD A WILDLY</h3>
         <p>You can edit all of this text and</br> replace it with anything you have</p>
         <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
     </div>
     <div class="box1">
         <img class='blog-image' src="images/img3-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
         <h3>9 STEPS TO STARTING A BUSINESS</h3>
         <p>This is a generic blog article you</br> can use for adding blog content</p>
         <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
     </div>
     <div class="box1">
         <img class='blog-image' src="images/img2-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
         <h3>7 BIG THINGS A START-UP MUST HAVE TO</h3>
         <p>You can also change the title</br> listed above and add new blog</p>
         <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
     </div>
     <div class="box1">
         <img class='blog-image' src="images/img4-service.jpg" width='250' height="175"/>
         <h3>HOW TO MAKE EXTRA MONEY</h3>
         <p>Edit your Blog articles from the</br> Pages tab by clicking th </p>
         <li><a>Read More ></a></li>
     </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: yeah, you can see that divs are not symmetric,how can I fix it

Comment: when media query 768px

Comment: .box1:nth-child(odd) {margin-left: 1rem ;} odd divs set with margin left 1rem thats why its bit left and set heading style

Comment: Addition Css     h1.topper-header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}